# How can I get the categories a product is in without including grandparents?

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

I'm trying to get a list of all products from the Magento 2 REST API and the categories the products are in (I want to build a tree-view in another application).

I can query for all SKUs then run through the SKUs one by one, but this takes a long time, I'd rather make 1 API call and get all product/category relationships in one go.

If I query all SKUs at once, I don't get the `category_ids` attribute which shows which categories the item belongs to.

`GET: http://someurl/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=`

```
// e.g. this is missing when querying for multiple SKUs
{
    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
    "value": [
        "557"
    ]
},
```

If I use the category API instead, it gives me products that belong to sub-categories under the current category, which I don't want.

`GET: http://someurl/rest/V1/categories/555/products`

```
// e.g. the below aren't leaf-level on category 555, they live in a subcategory
[
    {
        "sku": "BC000018",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "555"
    },
    {
        "sku": "BC000022",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "555"
    },
    {
        "sku": "BC000023",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "555"
    },
// and so on
```

Is there any way to query for only leaf-level items when inspecting categories, or any way to include detailed attributes when using the products API?

Comment: I've noticed I'm quite good at asking questions nobody knows the answer to :D

Comment: Can't you add the list in the returned json? So you have { list:[], products: [] }. You can run two seperate queries in order to fill this DTO.

Comment: The question is, how do I get that list in the first place with one API call - the data doesn't seem available via the API in this way without making many calls - this takes a couple of hours vs about 10 seconds using a single call... yet I get almost as much data from a single call (it's just missing the category IDs). I can do whatever I want with the DTO - that's not the issue, the issue is getting the data from the API without making thousands of round-trips to the REST services.

Comment: The API isn't yours? You cannot change the called method from the API?

Comment: No the API isn't mine...

Comment: You can't do it unless you can edit the api and add a new method which will do what you want. Give us the link to the api so we can see if it contains a method to getAllCategories or something.

Comment: It's the Magento 2 API - that's why I put the tag on and specified "The Magento 2 REST API", it's the same API for all people (unless you customise it which I can't do and don't want to), you don't need a link - just go to the Magento 2 API docs online and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for - you will need to build a custom Product Search / Product Details API, that returns a JSON resultset containing ALL pertinent data-points of interest (E.g: list of all categories a product is assigned to)

**My 2 cents:**

You might want to consider adding the additional data in the Product Details API Response and not into the "Product Node" of the Product Search's API.

*Here's why?*

Additional SQL queries may be needed to source the extra information you're looking to add to the Product JSON.

E.g: The `category - product` mappings are stored in the `catalog_category_product` table and will require atleast 1 extra SQL query.

Depending on your catalog size and/or category definitions, this additional query could add (best case scenario) 0.01 seconds - 0.5 seconds (in the case of complex/unoptimized table joints) per row to process.

If you have a catalog of 100 products - that meanss an extra 1 - 5 seconds to execute the Product Search API.
.
.
.
If you have a catalog of 1000 products - that means an extra 10 - 50 seconds to execute the Product Search API.
.
.
.
If you have a catalog of 10,000 products - that means an extra 100 - 500 seconds to execute the Product Search API.
.
.
.

You get the picture! :)

Good Luck!